# Single variable function derivative w.r.t. time?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I was studying calculus and I had doubts about this problem: (this is not homework)

*A circular wire expands due to heat so that its radius increases with a speed of $0.01 ms^{-1}$. How rapidly does the area increase when the radius is 2 cm?*

The solution goes like this:

Let *x* be the radius and *y* the area. Then:

$$y=\pi x^2$$

And then it goes like this:
$${dy\over{dt}}=2\pi x {dx\over{dt}}$$
How is this possible to do? *y* is a single variable function and *x* is just the independent variable.

This confuseses me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is why you should have never been taught that $f(x)$ means $y = ...$.  *Both* $y$ *and* $x$ are functions of $t$:

$$
y(t) = \pi x^2(t)
$$

Now differentiate both sides with respect to $t$--use the chain rule:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}y(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\pi x^2(t)\right) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 2\pi x \frac{dx}{dt}
$$

Here is another way to look at it:

$$
y = f(x) \\
\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$